# Can we test Dji Sdk with app without connecting to Drone (Actual Device)?? By any other means of virtual Device or using PC Simulator

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Can we test Dji Sdk with app without connecting to Drone (Actual Device)??By any other means of virtual Device or using  PC Simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You need one of the DJI drones to use the DJI SDK.